# How do I load instances of a certain class from a java directory?

Tags: java

Here's my method:

Feature[] getFeatures(File dir)

I'm trying to go through the directory, check each class file. Any class that is of type 'Feature', I want to load an instance of it. Then I want to return an array of these instances.

How is this done?

Thank you.

EDIT:

Here's what I have now:

```
private static LinkedList<Feature> getFeaturesInDirectory(File dir) throws ClassNotFoundException {

        LinkedList<Feature> features = new LinkedList<Feature>();

        ClassLoader cl = new IndFeaClassLoader();

        // list all files in directory
        for(String s : dir.list()) {
            Class klass = cl.loadClass(s);
            try {
                Object x = klass.newInstance();
                if (x instanceof Feature) {
                    features.add((Feature)x);
                }
            } catch (InstantiationException ex) {
            } catch (IllegalAccessException ex) {
            }

        }

        return features;

    }
```

Comment: It sounds like you want to create a classloader, load .class (or jar) files found in your dir?

Answer (score 1):

Using:

```
MyClassName mcn = (MyClassName) Class.forName("MyClassName").newInstance();
```

Note, however, that this relies on the ClassLoader. If the classes are not coming from the same location as your current class (or the system classloader) you need to specify a classloader:

```
File myDir = new File("/some/directory/");
ClassLoader loader = null;
try {
    URL url = myDir.toURL();         
    URL[] urls = new URL[]{url};
    ClassLoader loader = new URLClassLoader(urls);
} 
catch (MalformedURLException e) 
{
    // oops
}

MyClassName mcn = 
    (MyClassName) Class.forName("MyClassName", true, loader).newInstance();
```

I *think* that should work, but if not it should at least put you on the right path.

Comment: If he intended to use classpath (or an existing classloader) he probably won't have the 'dir' parameter?

Comment: @seand - I just edited actually, to try and clarify that. If he's trying to use random classes outside of where his current classes are loaded from, it's going to take some work, though I think the URLClassLoader might work, have to look.

Comment: I know I have to use a class loader, I'm just confused as to the method. I remember doing this before and I used something close to 'getSystemAsResourceStream'. I will try your method, Brian, and get back to you.

Comment: To clarify, I have packages that contain random classes. I'm looking to load instances of any classes that implement interface 'Feature'. So the ?s are: a) how to get all classes in package b) how to check class to see if it implements 'Feature'